# Accessing Validation.Errors from an ErrorTemplate

Tags: wpf, validation, xaml, controltemplate, errortemplate

I have a BindingGroup in a grid:

```
<Grid x:Name="участнКонтейн" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource участнПк}}"
    Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
  <Grid.BindingGroup>
    <BindingGroup NotifyOnValidationError="True">
      <BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
        <цл:валидУчастн ValidationStep="ConvertedProposedValue" />
      </BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
    </BindingGroup>
  </Grid.BindingGroup>
  <Grid.Style>
    <Style>
      <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource BindingGroupШаблОш}" />
    </Style>
  </Grid.Style>
  ...
```

And I have an ErrorTemplate for my Grid:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="BindingGroupШаблОш">
  <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="2">
    <StackPanel>
      <Label Content="My BindingGroup Error should be here!"></Label>
      <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
    </StackPanel>
  </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I want to access Validation.Errors[0].ErrorContent from my ControlTemplate to display it in my Label. Is it possible? Could you please help me?

Comment: +1 for a good, but surprisingly rare question. I quite agree that this solution is not widely published. I just posted a suggestion to MSDN on the Validation.ErrorTemplate Attached Property page requesting that they add this `DataContext = Validation.Errors` information, but we can only wait to see if they do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="BindingGroupШаблОш">
  <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="2">
    <StackPanel>
      <Label Content="{Binding Path=[0].ErrorContent}"></Label>
      <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
    </StackPanel>
  </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: I spend many hours reading MSDN, but I didn't find there the solution. And it is so easy. Where is it written? How do Microsoft think I should know that?

Comment: Yeh it is a strange thing. I had the same issue quite a while back and when `(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent` would not work, I just tried to set the `TextBlock` 's `Text` as it's `DataContext` just to see what it is as I'd read `ErrorTemplate`'s occupy a different Visual Layer above the actual control so `RelativeSource FindAncestor` wasn't going to work. It turned out the `DataContext` was the `ValidationError` class and thus tried to remove it from the path and it worked. I bet it's documented somewhere about the `DataContext` or someone's found it before :)

Comment: Me too,I tried to display something other than the error content.I've tried TemplateBinding, RelativeSource Self, tried different properties (e.g.Name, Width),but nothing was displayed.Finally I found a walkaround: instead of displaying the ErrorContent in an ErrorTemplate,I displayed it in the main window,but the Visibility property of the Label that displayed my error was bound to the HasError property of my validated BindingGroup. So when the error occures, the label is Visible, otherwise Collapsed. This worked fine, but it wasn't good and «beautiful». But your solution works great! Thanks.

Comment: +1 for a good solution and a good method for finding the solution. Shame I can't give you +2.